# Is there a way to make a download from a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: php, postgresql, download

I want to know if there is a way to make a download without having the file on the server.

To be more precise, my server run on a VM with very limited disk space (actually ~200 Mo of free space), and due to that fact, I have to use PostgreSQL on a different server.
The PostgreSQL base is huge (~60 million row per table, each month a new table is created and there is no limit to the number of table that can be created).

When I connect to my web page, I can choose to do a custon sql query, and the result of this query will be downloaded.
It's possible to have many sql query running at once and each query can take several minute, so I can't write the result query on a file in my server and after that do a classic download (with readfile).

So I have to mount a directory with cifs, fopen a file onto this directory, do the query, fetch row one by one and write this row into the file.

I want to get rid of the cifs mount, and I wonder if I can do the query and says to php to download the OPostgreSQL fetch. I don't know any other way to do a download other than the classical one.

If it's possible to do it via AJAX, it would be splendid.

EDIT :

I try this code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=toto');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Description: File Transfert');

$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:good_conn_info");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while ($data = $results->fetch()) {
    echo "${data['row']}\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

?>
```

and i only end up with "error connection : connection has been reinitialized".
Is this the rigth way ?

Comment: what *is* a download? simply your server sending data to the client, which the client saves instead of displaying. of course you can send data from the DB to the client. you just have to handle encoding, file headers, caching, ..... yourself, which normally the web server would do.

Comment: see also: [the PHP-manual for header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-examples) - for performance reasons, however, you should consider caching your file outputs *on* the CIFS share and reusing them whenever possible, since serving static files, even from a net share, automatically leverages caching and unburdens your database server.

Comment: I want to get rid of the cifs share. Or I do the cifs way, or I do the headers way without cifs. I can't keep the file on the cifs share.

Comment: I can't get that working. The webpage load and load and load and finally say "Connexion reinitialized". I can't find an example with a sql query ...

Comment: well, i'm afraid without *any* insight into your code *or* table structure, it is completely impossible to help you any further than pointing you at the example solution which you'd just have to use: a) send the headers, b) send the data c) done

Comment: Sorry. I updated my original post.

Comment: my first guess would be that your query simply times out. just for trying: could you add a "LIMIT 10" to your query and test if it works then? also: flushing after every echo decreases performance and flushing twice doesn't do any good.

Comment: Whit limit, even limit 1000, it's good. I'm aware that flushing after every echo isn't effecient, but I just want to have a response (after that, i can just flush after 20 echo or more). I see the flushing twice in a tutorial.
The real problem is that I can't know how many time it will requiert to do the query. Maybe I have to set the timeout to infinite ?